# Calculate the distance between two points

Tags: java, android

I tried the following code.but it gives two errors.I want calculate the distance between two points by formula line and display the result in the **textView1**. I do not know Where did I make the mistake in the code?

**Cal.java**

```
    import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Cal extends View {
Cal(Context context){
    super(context);
}
public double result;
double parameter = ((10-80)^2) + ((15-90)^2);
public void cal(){
    result = Math.sqrt(parameter);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   Cal cal;

    TextView textView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
 setContentView(R.id.textView1);
    cal = new Cal(this);
        textView.setText(cal).;
    }
}
```

**Errors:**

> Gradle:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Www:compileDebug'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

and

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.

Comment: What are the two errors you are getting? Kindly post them too!

Comment: I'm not familiar with android development but shouldn't `double parameter = ((10-80)^2) + ((15-90)^2);` be `double parameter = ((10-80)*(10-80)) + ((15-90)*(15-90));` ??

Comment: i guess setContentView(R.id.textView1);  and  textView.setText(cal); is the problem area both are not related with each other

Comment: `Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.` Could you also post the compiler logging?

Comment: I think cal object is as double. and it should change to string.But I do not know how?

Comment: Hi, This is not right. If you want to set the result value then you should first of all call the cal() method, then from there return the value back to the calling point and then store/display the value of the result. I would recommend to you that before going straight for android try doing some basic java codes in your notepad and try printing the outputs in the console. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.<your layout name>);  // You can not set id of any view here
    cal = new Cal(this);  // This is a object
    cal.cal();
    textView.setText(""+ cal.result);   // set the value instead of view object
    }
}
```

Comment: This will set the text view to value 0.0 as the result holds no value even after the constructor call.

Comment: Answer updated you have to call cal() function before setting result

Answer (score 0):

Make the cal() method return double value:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.Math;

    public class Cal extends View {
    Cal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public double result;
    double parameter = ((10-80)^2) + ((15-90)^2);
    public double cal(){
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Call the cal() method and display the result.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.<put your layout name here>); 
    cal = new Cal(this);  
    double res = cal.cal();
    textView.setText(""+res);   
    }
}
```

The textview will be set to "**NaN**" as your parameter variable is not a number variable.